# finding array values and comparing them?

Tags: php, arrays

```
ha15rs,250,home2.gif,2
ha36gs,150,home3.gif,1
ha27se,300,home4.gif,4
ha4678,200,home5.gif,5
```

when i turn this text file into array $handle, how can i test the second field `(250,150,300,200)`

i want to check if its below 100, if it is then display the row!!

```
if $secondfield < 100

then echo
```

how could i manipulate the array to do this in php thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple..

```
$h = file("file_name");

for ($x = 0; $x < count($h); $x++)
{
   $a = explode(",", $h[$x]);
   if ($a[1] < 100)
        echo $h[$x];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have each line in the file as an element in your array. In that case:

```
$data = array_map(function($e){ return explode(',', $e); }, $array);
$desiredData = array_filter(function($e){ return $e[1] < 100; }, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode every string, so you have four arrays:

```
foreach($strings as $string){
  $arr = expode(',', $string);

  if( intval($arr[1]) < 100 ){
    echo $string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a csv (I copied and modified some code from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)):

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        $data = str_getcsv($line);
        if ($data[1] < 100)
            echo $line;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: but you can't get the whole line to echo later (you could build it again but it's faster to have it ready)